# Offline installation of Visual Studio 2017 Update 2 (26430.04) fails

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, failed-installation

I'm running the command `mu_visual_studio_enterprise_2017_x86_x64_10049783.exe --layout c:\vs2017offline --lang en-US` to create an offline Visual Studio 2017 installer with the latest update 15.2 (26430.04). I have followed the instructions for offline installation and imported the certs etc. Still, on a machine without internet connection the installation fails. This has caused me major headaches as the failed installation corrupted my dev machine. Installation log attached below:

*The product failed to install the listed workloads and components due to one or more package failures.
Incomplete workloads
    .NET Core cross-platform development (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.NetCoreTools,version=15.0.26323.1)
    .NET desktop development (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.ManagedDesktop,version=15.0.26412.1)
    ASP.NET and web development (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.NetWeb,version=15.0.26412.1)
    Azure development (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.Azure,version=15.0.26412.1)
    Data storage and processing (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.Data,version=15.0.26208.0)
    Universal Windows Platform development (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.Universal,version=15.0.26403.0)
Incomplete components
    .NET desktop development tools (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.ManagedDesktop.Prerequisites,version=15.0.26323.1)
    ASP.NET and web development tools (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Web,version=15.0.26323.1)
    Azure Cloud Services core tools (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Azure.Waverton,version=15.0.26208.0)
    Azure Cloud Services tools (Microsoft.VisualStudio.ComponentGroup.Azure.CloudServices,version=15.0.26208.0)
    Azure Data Lake Tools (Microsoft.Component.Azure.DataLake.Tools,version=15.0.26208.0)
    Azure development prerequisites (Microsoft.VisualStudio.ComponentGroup.Azure.Prerequisites,version=15.0.26323.1)
    Azure Resource Manager core tools (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Azure.ResourceManager.Tools,version=15.0.26208.0)
    Azure Resource Manager tools (Microsoft.VisualStudio.ComponentGroup.Azure.ResourceManager.Tools,version=15.0.26323.1)
    C# and Visual Basic (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Roslyn.LanguageServices,version=15.0.26208.0)
    Data sources for SQL Server support (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.SQL.DataSources,version=15.0.26208.0)
    Live Unit Testing (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.LiveUnitTesting,version=15.0.26208.0)
    Managed Desktop Workload Core (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.ManagedDesktop.Core,version=15.0.26419.1)
    Microsoft Test Manager (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.TestTools.MicrosoftTestManager,version=15.0.26228.0)
    OzCode (Component.6c84f75d-38c3-48a2-9e54-d362238686b5,version=3.0.0.3597)
    PowerShell Tools for Visual Studio 2017 (Component.PowerShellTools.VS2017,version=3.0.539)
    ReadyRoll for VS2017 (Component.Redgate.ReadyRoll,version=1.13.23.3401)
    SQL Prompt Core (Component.Redgate.SQLPrompt.VsPackage,version=7.5.1.1087)
    SQL Search (Component.Redgate.SQLSearch.VSExtension,version=2.4.2.1321)
    SQL Server Data Tools (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.SQL.SSDT,version=15.0.26208.0)
    Testing tools core features (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.TestTools.Core,version=15.0.26208.0)
    Universal Windows Platform tools (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.UWP.Support,version=15.0.26412.1)
    Universal Windows Platform tools for Xamarin (Microsoft.VisualStudio.ComponentGroup.UWP.Xamarin,version=15.0.26403.0)
    Web performance and load testing tools (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.TestTools.WebLoadTest,version=15.0.26208.0)
    Windows Communication Foundation (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Wcf.Tooling,version=15.0.26208.0)
    Windows Workflow Foundation (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Workflow,version=15.0.26208.0)
You can search for solutions using the information below, modify your selections for the above workloads and components and retry the installation, or remove the product from your machine.
Following is a collection of individual package failures that led to the incomplete workloads and components above. To search for existing reports of these specific problems, please copy and paste the URL from each package failure into a web browser. If the issue has already been reported, you can find solutions or workarounds there. If the issue has not been reported, you can create a new issue where other people will be able to find solutions or workarounds.
Package 'Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.VisualStudio.InteractiveComponents.Resources,version=15.0.26412.1,language=en-US' failed to download from 'https://download.microsoft.com/download/1/9/A/19A9B545-B70C-4B0E-871D-CEF22A55E2A8/microsoft.codeanalysis.visualstudio.interactivecomponents.resources.vsix'.
    Search URL: https://aka.ms/VSSetupErrorReports?q=PackageId=Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.VisualStudio.InteractiveComponents.Resources;PackageAction=DownloadPackage;ReturnCode=0x80072ee7
    Impacted workloads
        .NET Core cross-platform development (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.NetCoreTools,version=15.0.26323.1)
        .NET desktop development (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.ManagedDesktop,version=15.0.26412.1)
        ASP.NET and web development (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.NetWeb,version=15.0.26412.1)
        Azure development (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.Azure,version=15.0.26412.1)
        Data storage and processing (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.Data,version=15.0.26208.0)
        Universal Windows Platform development (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.Universal,version=15.0.26403.0)
    Impacted components
        .NET desktop development tools (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.ManagedDesktop.Prerequisites,version=15.0.26323.1)
        ASP.NET and web development tools (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Web,version=15.0.26323.1)
        Azure Cloud Services core tools (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Azure.Waverton,version=15.0.26208.0)
        Azure Cloud Services tools (Microsoft.VisualStudio.ComponentGroup.Azure.CloudServices,version=15.0.26208.0)
        Azure Data Lake Tools (Microsoft.Component.Azure.DataLake.Tools,version=15.0.26208.0)
        Azure Resource Manager core tools (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Azure.ResourceManager.Tools,version=15.0.26208.0)
        Azure Resource Manager tools (Microsoft.VisualStudio.ComponentGroup.Azure.ResourceManager.Tools,version=15.0.26323.1)
        C# and Visual Basic (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Roslyn.LanguageServices,version=15.0.26208.0)
        Data sources for SQL Server support (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.SQL.DataSources,version=15.0.26208.0)
        Live Unit Testing (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.LiveUnitTesting,version=15.0.26208.0)
        Managed Desktop Workload Core (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.ManagedDesktop.Core,version=15.0.26419.1)
        OzCode (Component.6c84f75d-38c3-48a2-9e54-d362238686b5,version=3.0.0.3597)
        PowerShell Tools for Visual Studio 2017 (Component.PowerShellTools.VS2017,version=3.0.539)
        ReadyRoll for VS2017 (Component.Redgate.ReadyRoll,version=1.13.23.3401)
        SQL Prompt Core (Component.Redgate.SQLPrompt.VsPackage,version=7.5.1.1087)
        SQL Search (Component.Redgate.SQLSearch.VSExtension,version=2.4.2.1321)
        SQL Server Data Tools (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.SQL.SSDT,version=15.0.26208.0)
        Universal Windows Platform tools (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.UWP.Support,version=15.0.26412.1)
        Web performance and load testing tools (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.TestTools.WebLoadTest,version=15.0.26208.0)
        Windows Communication Foundation (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Wcf.Tooling,version=15.0.26208.0)
        Windows Workflow Foundation (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Workflow,version=15.0.26208.0)
    Details
        WebClient download failed: The remote name could not be resolved: 'download.microsoft.com'
        Bits download failed: File not found.
        WinInet download failed: Function: InternetOpenUrl, HR: -2147012889, Message: Unknown error 12007
Package 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.TestPlatform.Legacy.Core.Resources,version=15.0.26424.2,language=en-US' failed to download from 'https://download.microsoft.com/download/D/3/0/D3037781-3854-46BA-B6BC-7744B2A41FF1/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.testplatform.legacy.core.resources.vsix'.
    Search URL: https://aka.ms/VSSetupErrorReports?q=PackageId=Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.TestPlatform.Legacy.Core.Resources;PackageAction=DownloadPackage;ReturnCode=0x80072ee7
    Impacted workloads
        .NET Core cross-platform development (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.NetCoreTools,version=15.0.26323.1)
        .NET desktop development (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.ManagedDesktop,version=15.0.26412.1)
        ASP.NET and web development (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.NetWeb,version=15.0.26412.1)
        Azure development (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.Azure,version=15.0.26412.1)
        Data storage and processing (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.Data,version=15.0.26208.0)
        Universal Windows Platform development (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.Universal,version=15.0.26403.0)
    Impacted components
        .NET desktop development tools (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.ManagedDesktop.Prerequisites,version=15.0.26323.1)
        ASP.NET and web development tools (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Web,version=15.0.26323.1)
        Azure Cloud Services core tools (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Azure.Waverton,version=15.0.26208.0)
        Azure Cloud Services tools (Microsoft.VisualStudio.ComponentGroup.Azure.CloudServices,version=15.0.26208.0)
        Azure Data Lake Tools (Microsoft.Component.Azure.DataLake.Tools,version=15.0.26208.0)
        Azure development prerequisites (Microsoft.VisualStudio.ComponentGroup.Azure.Prerequisites,version=15.0.26323.1)
        Azure Resource Manager core tools (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Azure.ResourceManager.Tools,version=15.0.26208.0)
        Azure Resource Manager tools (Microsoft.VisualStudio.ComponentGroup.Azure.ResourceManager.Tools,version=15.0.26323.1)
        Data sources for SQL Server support (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.SQL.DataSources,version=15.0.26208.0)
        Managed Desktop Workload Core (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.ManagedDesktop.Core,version=15.0.26419.1)
        Microsoft Test Manager (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.TestTools.MicrosoftTestManager,version=15.0.26228.0)
        PowerShell Tools for Visual Studio 2017 (Component.PowerShellTools.VS2017,version=3.0.539)
        ReadyRoll for VS2017 (Component.Redgate.ReadyRoll,version=1.13.23.3401)
        SQL Prompt Core (Component.Redgate.SQLPrompt.VsPackage,version=7.5.1.1087)
        SQL Search (Component.Redgate.SQLSearch.VSExtension,version=2.4.2.1321)
        SQL Server Data Tools (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.SQL.SSDT,version=15.0.26208.0)
        Testing tools core features (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.TestTools.Core,version=15.0.26208.0)
        Universal Windows Platform tools (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.UWP.Support,version=15.0.26412.1)
        Universal Windows Platform tools for Xamarin (Microsoft.VisualStudio.ComponentGroup.UWP.Xamarin,version=15.0.26403.0)
        Web performance and load testing tools (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.TestTools.WebLoadTest,version=15.0.26208.0)
        Windows Workflow Foundation (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Workflow,version=15.0.26208.0)
    Details
        WebClient download failed: The remote name could not be resolved: 'download.microsoft.com'
        Bits download failed: File not found.
        WinInet download failed: Function: InternetOpenUrl, HR: -2147012889, Message: Unknown error 12007
Package 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.TestManagement.MicrosoftTestManager.Resources,version=15.0.26424.2,language=en-US' failed to download from 'https://download.microsoft.com/download/6/3/5/635106B1-58AD-4D74-B069-9942F0654B95/MS.VS.TestTools.TestManagement.MSTestManager.Resources.vsix'.
    Search URL: https://aka.ms/VSSetupErrorReports?q=PackageId=Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.TestManagement.MicrosoftTestManager.Resources;PackageAction=DownloadPackage;ReturnCode=0x80072ee7
    Impacted components
        Microsoft Test Manager (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.TestTools.MicrosoftTestManager,version=15.0.26228.0)
    Details
        WebClient download failed: The remote name could not be resolved: 'download.microsoft.com'
        Bits download failed: File not found.
        WinInet download failed: Function: InternetOpenUrl, HR: -2147012889, Message: Unknown error 12007*

Comment: Check your network first. 'Fail to download ...'

Comment: Nothing wrong with my network. Downloaded v26430.04 on different machines in different environments. Installation fails with same error. I've performed offline installation with previous versions of VS2017, which worked fine.

Comment: `"the remote name could not be resolved: 'download.microsoft.com'" `sounds like a DNS issue

Comment: I did downloaded the file with that link. It is a valid link. So check your network?

Comment: I understand that. This log is from a machine without internet connection. The installation shouldn't attempt making a connection to the internet. The offline installer should have what it needs to complete the installation without internet connectivity.

Comment: What command did you use to create you offline installer? Did you run the installation on a machine without internet connectivity?

Comment: Offline installation is bullshit , I do not know why Microsoft doing this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you didn't include the `--includeRecommended` and `--includeOptional` parameters in your **offline layout** command, this is required because it only downloads required packages by default which is not sufficient for the installation to work offline.

Comment: Today I created a offline layout of the latest VS 2017 release v26430.06. Including the --includeRecommended and --includeOptional parameters in the command worked. Cheers

Comment: You don't have to add those switches for setup to work offline or for your workload project to function, trust me, you'll end with a massive size layout.

Answer (score 1):

***The problem is: The `--layout` switch should be used ONLY when downloading a new workload or updating one***, which off-course need to be done online, which makes the above error.

By just saying **`--layout`** you ask setup: "please update the components in this layout, I'm online now.", which 1st downlaod ~ 60MB file saying "Give us more time, we'll be done soon", then start updating.

When you want to setup vs2017:

1. Open the 3 certificates in **`[layoutFolder]\certificates`**, press enter
   or next on each dialog till you finish, don't change anything.
2. Run **`[layoutFolder]\vs_*.exe`**.

However, Its highly recommended to automate the run of vs_*.exe (for setup to choose the exactly Required components) like that:

### `.\layout\vs_setup.exe --add microsoft.visualstudio.workload.ManagedDesktop --nocache`

You don't need to even specify: **`--lang en-US`**. **`--nocache`** will save your C: from same-as-installed-workload-size additional GB's.

Answer (score 0):

You can do manual download https://download.microsoft.com/download/1/9/A/19A9B545-B70C-4B0E-871D-CEF22A55E2A8/microsoft.codeanalysis.visualstudio.interactivecomponents.resources.vsix  and put it to folder "Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.VisualStudio.InteractiveComponents.Resources,version=15.0.26412.1,language=en-US" , file name must be "microsoft.codeanalysis.visualstudio.interactivecomponents.resources.vsix"